# move div towards mouse at same speed per second

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created the following code to make the player move towards the mouse, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kh41tzfy/3/)

**Code**

```
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    mouseX = event.pageX;
    mouseY = event.pageY;
});

$(function(){
    var $map = $(".map");
    var $player = $('.player');

    var centerPlayerX = $player.offset().left + $player.width() / 2;
    var centerPlayerY = $player.offset().top + $player.height() / 2;

    var movingInterval;
    $('.map').on('mousedown', function(event){
            movingInterval = setInterval(function(){
            var clickedPosX = mouseX,
                clickedPosY = mouseY;

            var currentMapPositionX = parseFloat($map.css("background-position-x"));
            var currentMapPositionY = parseFloat($map.css("background-position-y"));

            var moveMapX = currentMapPositionX - clickedPosX/100 + centerPlayerX/100;
            var moveMapY = currentMapPositionY - clickedPosY/100 + centerPlayerY/100;

            $map.css({ "background-position-x": `${moveMapX}px`, "background-position-y":  `${moveMapY}px` });

            var angle = getDirection(centerPlayerX, clickedPosY, clickedPosX, centerPlayerY);
            $player.find('.ship').css('transform', 'rotate('+angle+'deg)');
            }, 10);
    }).on('mouseup', function() {
           clearInterval(movingInterval);
        });;
});

function getDirection(x1, y1, x2, y2){
  var dx = x2 - x1;
  var dy = y2 - y1;

  return Math.atan2(dx,  dy) / Math.PI * 180;
}
```

**Problem**

```
    var moveMapX = currentMapPositionX - clickedPosX/100 + centerPlayerX/100;
        var moveMapY = currentMapPositionY - clickedPosY/100 + centerPlayerY/100;
```

Problem is that I want to move the player at a set speed (px*ps). Currently the player will increase in speed when the player moves his mouse further away from the image. I currently have no idea on how I would move the player at a set speed. Therefore I would need to remove clickedPosY/X somehow and change it to a static speed but the image should still move towards were the mouse is, which is the problem.

Comment: I think you would need to craft a formula using $(window).height()/width() and then determining which quadrant of the screen the mouse is in, then you could use that value to fill a static rate to subtract that would move the background in the correct direction.

Comment: This is kind of what I was thinking, it needs more work because transitioning between the quadrants in jerky; https://jsfiddle.net/73s1q0v0/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, let's assume you have a speed constant; what you want to do is to project the speed constant along the movement vector.  The easiest way to do that is to scale the components of the offset to the click position by the ratio of the speed to the distance between the click point and the movement base:

```
var distanceX = clickedPosX - centerPlayerX;
var distanceY = clickedPosY - centerPlayerY;

var magnitude = Math.sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY);
var deltaX = distanceX * speed / magnitude;
var deltaY = distanceY * speed / magnitude;

var moveMapX = currentMapPositionX - deltaX;
var moveMapY = currentMapPositionY - deltaY;
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/117ft1Lf/4/)

Comment: More than awesome!